# ARMsim: input-wait loop swi 0x203 0x202

Tags: arm

I'm practicing ARM on ARMsim 1.9.1

I was wondering how one could make a program wait for an input from the EmbestBoard (from either the Blue Keyboard or the Black Buttons). I noticed none of the button patterns is 0x0 so I thought of this solution:

```
    .text
```

`ENTRY`:

`check_input:`

`swi    0x203   ;0x202 (same problem)`

`cmp    r0,#0`

`beq    check_input`

`mov    r0,#0`

`adr    r2,line`

`swi    0x204`

`@memory operands:`

`line:  .asciz  "Input was received"`

```
.end
```

If I execute the program step by step it works magnificently but if I just run the program I need to press the button twice, before an input is recognized. Apparently the simulated processor ignores the first input. How can I avert this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This would appear to be a UI problem. From some brief experimentation, it's not that "the simulated processor ignores the first input", it's that clicking the run button does something weird with the focus<sup>*</sup>, so you have to click *anywhere* in the window (or switch to another window and back) before it starts registering clicks or even mouse movement properly again. That'll be where your first click is disappearing to.

<sub>* From my Win32 days, I recall that disabling a dialog control while it has focus is considered A Bad Thing and can confuse the window manager; that might be what's happening here.</sub>

Comment: That's it! I have just tried running the program by pressing F5 instead of clicking on the _Run_ button and the problem doesn't show up.